# Can't start Grails app from GGTS on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: eclipse, grails, ubuntu

I am encountering the following error when trying to start a Grails app using the menu option `Run as | Grails Command (run-app)` in GGTS

`Error executing script RunApp: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "grails": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)`

I have the following exports in `.bashrc`:

`export GRAILS_HOME=/home/<my_home_folder>/springsource/grails-2.2.2`

`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle`

`export PATH=$PATH:$GRAILS_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin`

And I've made everything in GRAILS_HOME/bin executable.

If I open the grails shell, I can start my app using run-app without any trouble. It's just in GGTS that I have this problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Has this started happening recently ? have you tried testing a new project in a new work space. I would test a new workspace and if that does not work try moving .grails from your home folder and attempting a new startup. Before doing all of that go to the properties of your project Java Build Path and Java Libraries ensure nothing has red crosses. You should have Grails Dependencies Groovy DSL and JRE system lib.. compare JREs here to your bashrc too.. As for paths I have no GGTS set on my profile.. env  |egrep -I "(grails|java)" returns nothing

Comment: I'm setting up a new Ubuntu machine - I've previously worked on the project using two different osx machines. Neither of these seemed to have a problem finding the grails executable when running in GGTS. I'm using the same JDK for both GGTS and the rest of the OS. The interesting thing is I've had exactly this error before when trying to get a Grails project building in Jenkins on Ubuntu. I think that was down to permissions of the grails wrapper though so not directly applicable to this situation.

Comment: Hi, I would still suggest after ggts download to start a new workspace and attempt run app on a new project if this works. Then Try creating new workspace same project name then copy from existing project the grails-app and Web apps folder across to it. Refresh new project. Attempt run app again .

Comment: The for the suggestion, unfortunately the new workspace / new project test didn't work either. My work around for now is just to run grails from the command line.

Comment: Just to give you an update, I tried downloading the latest version of GGTS (3.4 M1 appears to have been released in the last few days), and I've managed to get a new project to run in a clean workspace under Grails 2.2.4. I'm not sure exactly why things are behaving differently now but I'm just pleased to be up and running in GGTS again.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, is anyone able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the menu `Window` > select `Preferences` > select `Groovy` >  select `Grails` and add your Grails installation (Enter something like 'Grails 2.2.2' and browse to the Grails installation directory).

If you want a Grails version (e.g. 2.2.4) on project that is different than the workspace version (e.g. 2.2.2), then right click on the project > select `properties` > select `Grails` > check `Enable project specific settings`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I already have the grails runtime configured in GGTS. As far as I can tell, everything is set up in exactly the same was as on my osx machine (which works fine). I think for now I'm just going to run grails from the command line (My main concern was that I wanted to use the GGTS debugger, but I've found I can debug remotely using grails-debug and connecting on port 5005)

Comment: Did you use the GGTS .sh installer or the tar.gz file?  And what version of the GGTS are you on?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I downloaded and ran the .sh (but I'm trying this again as we speak). Latest version of 64 bit GGTS (3.3.0 based on Eclipse 4.3)